# Searching and Reading from file

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if it is possible to search and read from a file and display what's in the file in a message box.

I'm wanting to search for a file by its ID, which ID is known by the user. When the user enters the ID my program opens the file which shares the same ID; eg.ID.txt in the preset folder.

when it's selected it is then read and put in a MessageBox which will then display what is in the file.

Can anyone show me how to do this?
Thanks.

```
 //Declare variables
    int TID;


    private void TIDFileCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamWriter outputFile;
        outputFile = File.CreateText (TID.ToString()+".txt");

        outputFile.WriteLine("Investor :" +" " + InvestorNameLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Initial Amount" + " " +AmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Date Invested" +" " +DateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Period Chosen" + " "+DaysInvestedLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Rate Chosen" + " " + RateLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Total Interest" + " " +InterestAmountLabel.Text);
        outputFile.WriteLine("Transaction Number :" + " " + TransactionIDLabel.Text);
        outputFile.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Transaction file for Transaction: " + TransactionIDLabel.Text + "Was Created", "Transaction File");

    }

    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchID = int.Parse(searchTextBox.Text);
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\"+SearchID+".txt");
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain what part causes problem? (Note that you already have sample of reading from a file and showing message box in your post, so I assume you are looking for manual on `String.IndexOf`)...

Comment: Yeah. What exactly is your problem? Are you receiving an exception? Do  you need to parse the contents of the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use `MessageBox.Show()` in your `SearchButton_Click` method?

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchID = int.Parse(searchTextBox.Text);
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\"+SearchID+".txt");
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\r\n", lines));
}
```

Comment: For me the 
       MessageBox.Show(lines); doesn't work as it doesnt exist in the current context and there is an identifier expected at string{}

Answer (score 0):

I think that for what you want to do you should read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx
or some similar article about serialization.
This said, if the number of IDs grow in number, you should considering the adoption of a lightweight DB, i.e. SQLite, just to name one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `DirectoryInfo` class. Something like the following should do what you want;

```
    DirecectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(pathToRoot);
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("Id.txt"); //if using a specific name should return 1 item
    TextBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(files.FirstOrDefault().FullName);
```

Keep in mind I have no error handling or anything here. You'll have to add that yourself, this just shows you the key classes/methods to get the files and read their contents. There are many other options like doing `GetFiles()`, keeping that collection in memory and then operating on them later on.